# MVP Architecture implementation in powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

In the project, We want to implement the MVP architecture in Powerbuilder. we don't know how to implement this.

So can somebody provide me the essence of MVP for Powerbuilder? I Would appreciate a couple of examples.

Comment: Is this an 'intellectual pursuit' or a real world application?  What advantages do you think you will gain by this?

Answer (score 0):

It may interest you: [Apply MVP pattern in PowerBuilder Application](https://maonet.wordpress.com/2008/02/21/apply-mvp-pattern-in-powerbuilder-application/)

Comment: I read that article already before you answer. Could you please provide the other articles for implementation of MVP architecture in Powerbuilder?

Comment: MVP is not an architecture to implement with PowerBuilder, you can make an invention based on the documentation that I have provided. More documentation I do not have and I do not find. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A google search would bring enough articles on howto use the MVP pattern.
For example the following article:
https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html

You should read and understand what is written there.
Then you could create a simple test project.

You simply need 3 objects.

1. POCO object
2. a window
3. a presenter object which holds a reference to your window and your POCO

When your window would have a Edit-Control on it and a normal Button, then your presenter should have at least the following methods

- of_OnOkButtonClicked()
- of_OnTextChanged(string value)
- of_OnCloseingDialog()
- of_ShowDialog(bool modal)
- of_ModelToView()
- of_ViewToModel()

Now you should be able to create a working sample on your own.